# Using API KEY in to retrieve activities from google plus is not working

Tags: java, google-plus, google-api-java-client

I'm using APIKEY to set up the transport and initialize the connection to retrieve activities from Google Plus.

```
HttpRequestInitializer initializer =  (HttpRequestInitializer) new  CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer("GooglePlusAPIKey");  
plusSvc = new Plus(new NetHttpTransport(),  new GsonFactory(), initializer);
```

It gives me this error:

> `CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer` cannot be cast to `HttpRequestInitializer`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is correct.  HttpRequestInitializer and CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer  are not directly related, so the cast is illegal.  They are just similar classes in different packages -- you cannot mix-n-match like this.

See docs here: http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.12.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer.html

The examples here may be easier to follow: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

Comment: Thank you very much :)..
Im using the the Java client library for google+ 1.14 and its different than the previous versions. 
I followed the api document and it was said to use CommonGoogleJsonClientRequestInitializer instead of GoogleKeyInitializer and HttpRequestInitializer isntead of JsonHttpRequestInitializer

I need to know how to set the APIKEY and to set the Plus variable using Java client library 1.14

Thank you :)